# Created mongod replication Set but fail to connect

Tags: mongodb, shell, replication, database

I have created mongoDB replication set using this command:

> F:\data>mongod --replSet set1 --dbpath 1 --port 27101
>   --oplogSize 50 --logpath log.1 --logappend --fork

It does not recognize `--fork` and it is not there in `--help` as well (I guess) so I have excluded it and got following output. I think there is nothing wrong so far.

```
all output going to: log.1
```

Then when I try to use mongo console using this command

```
F:\data>mongo --port 27101
```

It returns

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.2.2
connecting to: 127.0.0.1:27101/test
Thu Feb 14 01:36:33 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27101 src/mongo/
shell/mongo.js:93
exception: connect failed
```

Now what can be done to make it work?

Comment: And what is in `log.1`?

Comment: What Vasiliy said, and what does ps ax | grep mongod give you? Also, try changing the position of --fork option like so: 
mongod --fork --replSet set1 offset --dbpath 1 --port 27101 --oplogSize 50 --logpath log.1 --logappend

Comment: It will keep a log file in data directory @VasiliyFaronov

Comment: Can you post the contents of this log file?

Comment: @AlptiginJalayr can you please repeat your instruction or query?

Comment: `ps ax | grep mongod` returned nothing! just blank! What does it do! :S @AlptiginJalayr

Comment: we checked to see if the Mongo Daemon was executing. Now, what are the contents of that log?

Comment: Thankyou @AlptiginJalayr problem solved. It needs a directory called "1" on my current directory but I had created it inside `data/db` :D

Comment: ok, cheers. Please post your solution as an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I in the parameter I had this data path `--dbpath 1` so I need to have a directory named '1' in my current directory but I had created it in `data` directory by misunderstanding.

Thankyou `@Alptigin Jalayr` and others who has lead me to the correct direction.